# Not able to Push Log Data using KAA 0.10 C SDK

Tags: kaa

We have created one local cloud instance using KAA 0.10 and generated C Posix SDK after adding some Log Upload Schema.

I have created one sample program in which just create one KAA client and update dummy endpoints and started KAA client in which one dummy callback function will be called which is working fine without any issue.

After that, I have extended my working code to upload Log Data on some events like every 1 seconds or every 5 logs count and executed same code on my Linux System but I am getting "failed_log_delivery_callback" randomly not as per strategy defined.

Please find following code which I am using to check Log Upload Strategy using KAA 0.10 C SDK.

```
/* Set of routines that handles log delivery events */
static void success_log_delivery_callback(void *context, const kaa_log_bucket_info_t *bucket)
{
    printf("+++++++++++++++++ success_log_delivery_callback called +++++++++++++++++++++++\n");

    printf("Bucket: %u is successfully delivered. Logs uploaded: %zu\n",
           bucket->bucket_id,
           bucket->log_count);
}

static void failed_log_delivery_callback(void *context, const kaa_log_bucket_info_t *bucket)
{
    printf("+++++++++++++++++ failed_log_delivery_callback called +++++++++++++++++++++++\n");

    printf("Log delivery of the bucket: %u is failed!\n", bucket->bucket_id);
}

static void timeout_log_delivery_callback(void *context, const kaa_log_bucket_info_t *bucket)
{
    printf("+++++++++++++++++ timeout_log_delivery_callback called +++++++++++++++++++++++\n");

    printf("Timeout reached for log delivery of the bucket: %u!\n", bucket->bucket_id);
}

/* Log delivery listener callbacks. Each callback called whenever something happen with a log bucket. */
kaa_log_delivery_listener_t log_listener = {
     .on_success = success_log_delivery_callback,   /* Called if log delivered successfully */
     .on_failed  = failed_log_delivery_callback,    /* Called if delivery failed */
     .on_timeout = timeout_log_delivery_callback,   /* Called if timeout occurs */
     .ctx        = NULL,                            /* Optional context */
};

kaa_union_t *kaa_logging_union_create(const char *data, uint8_t type, destroy_fn destroy)
{
    kaa_union_t *str;
    str = kaa_logging_union_string_or_null_branch_0_create();
    str->data = kaa_string_move_create(data,NULL);

    return str;
}

kaa_union_t *kaa_profile_union_create(const char *data, uint8_t type, destroy_fn destroy)
{
    kaa_union_t *str;
    str = kaa_logging_union_string_or_null_branch_0_create();
    str->data = kaa_string_move_create(data,NULL);

    return str;
}

static void dummy_function(void *context)
{
    kaa_error_t error_code = 0;

    printf("\n\n**************** Hello, I am a Kaa Application!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n\n");

    kaa_logging_event_push_t *log_push;

    /* Log information. Populated when log is added via kaa_logging_add_record() */
    kaa_log_record_info_t log_info;

    /* kaa logging event push data will be created from here */
    log_push = kaa_logging_event_push_create();

    if(log_push == NULL)
    {
        printf("can not create log data\r\n");
        kaa_client_stop(kaa_client);
        return;
    }

    log_push->tag = kaa_logging_union_create("67891",0,NULL);
    if(log_push->tag == NULL)
    {
        printf("can not create log data\r\n");
        kaa_client_stop(kaa_client);
        return;
    }

    log_push->rid = kaa_logging_union_create("77:88:99:11:22:33",0,NULL);
    if(log_push->rid == NULL)
    {
        printf("can not create log data\r\n");
        kaa_client_stop(kaa_client);
        return;
    }

    log_push->var = kaa_logging_union_create("HIJKLMN",0,NULL);
    if(log_push->var == NULL)
    {
        printf("can not create log data\r\n");
        kaa_client_stop(kaa_client);
        return;
    }

    log_push->payload = kaa_string_move_create("Linux System KAA Message",NULL);
    if(log_push->payload == NULL)
    {
        printf("can not create log data\r\n");
        kaa_client_stop(kaa_client);
        return;
    }

    /* kaa logging push data will be added from here */
    error_code = kaa_logging_add_record(kaa_client_get_context(kaa_client)->log_collector, log_push, &log_info);
    if (error_code) 
    {
        printf("Failed to add log record, error code %d\n", error_code);
        kaa_client_stop(kaa_client);
        return;
    }

    printf("log message added :: count :: %d\r\n", kaa_log_count);

    /* kaa logging push data will be destroyed from here */
    log_push->destroy(log_push);

    kaa_log_count++;

    /* kaa client will be stopped from here */
    /*error_code = kaa_client_stop(kaa_client);
    if (error_code) 
    {
        printf("kaa_client_stop is failed to execute.....\n");
        return;
    }
    else
        printf("kaa_client_stop is executed successfully.....\n");  */
}

int main(void)
{
    kaa_error_t error_code = 0;
    int i = 0;
    void *log_storage_context = NULL, *log_upload_strategy_context = NULL;

    printf("*********** kaa_basic_main started **************\n");

    kaa_profile_t *profile = NULL;

    printf("Before kaa_client_create API...\n");

    /* kaa client will be created from here */
    error_code = kaa_client_create(&kaa_client, NULL);
    if (error_code) 
    {
        printf("kaa_client_create API is failed to execute...\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else
        printf("kaa_client_create API is called successfully...\n");

    sleep(2);

    kaa_endpoint_id_p buff = (kaa_endpoint_id_p)malloc(23);

    /* kaa profile manager endpoint id comes from here */
    error_code = kaa_profile_manager_get_endpoint_id(kaa_client_get_context(kaa_client)->profile_manager,buff);
    if (error_code) 
    {
        printf("kaa_profile_manager_get_endpoint_id is failed to execute.....\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else
    {
        for(i = 0; i < 23; i++)
        {
            printf("kaa_profile_manager_get_endpoint_id[i] :: 0x%x\n", buff[i]);
        }


        printf("kaa_profile_manager_get_endpoint_id API is called successfully...\n");
    }

    free(buff);

    /* kaa profile will be created from here */
    profile = (kaa_profile_t *)kaa_profile_profile_create();

    printf("kaa_profile_profile_create API is called...\n");

    profile->id     = kaa_string_move_create(id,NULL);
    profile->key    = kaa_string_move_create((const char *)key,NULL);
    profile->current_firmware_version = kaa_string_move_create(f_version,NULL);
    profile->serial_number = kaa_string_move_create(ser_number,NULL);
    profile->health    = kaa_string_move_create(health,NULL);
    profile->pii    = kaa_string_move_create(pii,NULL);
    profile->info    = kaa_string_move_create(info,NULL);

    sleep(2);

    printf("before kaa_profile_manager_update_profile API is called...\n");

    /* kaa profile will be updated from here */
    error_code = kaa_profile_manager_update_profile(kaa_client_get_context(kaa_client)->profile_manager, profile);
    if (error_code) 
    {
        printf("kaa_profile_manager_update_profile is failed to execute.....\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else
        printf("kaa_profile_manager_update_profile API is called successfully...\n");

    sleep(2);

    printf("before calling kaa_client_start.....\n");

    /* The internal memory log storage distributed with Kaa SDK */
    error_code = ext_unlimited_log_storage_create(&log_storage_context, kaa_client_get_context(kaa_client)->logger);
    if (error_code) 
    {
        printf("ext_unlimited_log_storage_create is failed to execute.....\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else
        printf("ext_unlimited_log_storage_create is executed successfully.....\n");

    /* KAA Upload Strategy will be created with timeout */
    error_code = ext_log_upload_strategy_create(kaa_client_get_context(kaa_client), &log_upload_strategy_context, KAA_LOG_UPLOAD_BY_TIMEOUT_STRATEGY);
    if (error_code) 
    {
        printf("ext_log_upload_strategy_create is failed to execute.....\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else
        printf("ext_log_upload_strategy_create is executed successfully.....\n");

    /* Strategy will upload logs every 1 seconds. */
    error_code = ext_log_upload_strategy_set_upload_timeout(log_upload_strategy_context, 1);
    if (error_code) 
    {
        printf("ext_log_upload_strategy_set_threshold_count is failed to execute.....\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else
        printf("ext_log_upload_strategy_set_threshold_count is executed successfully.....\n");

    /* Specify log bucket size constraints */
    kaa_log_bucket_constraints_t bucket_sizes = {
         .max_bucket_size       = 512,  /* Bucket size in bytes */
         .max_bucket_log_count  = 5,    /* Maximum log count in one bucket */
    };

    /* Initialize the log storage and strategy (by default it is not set) */
    error_code = kaa_logging_init(kaa_client_get_context(kaa_client)->log_collector
                                  , log_storage_context
                                  , log_upload_strategy_context
                                  , &bucket_sizes);
    if (error_code) 
    {
        printf("kaa_logging_init is failed to execute.....\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else
        printf("kaa_logging_init is executed successfully.....\n"); 

    /* Add listeners to a log collector */
    kaa_logging_set_listeners(kaa_client_get_context(kaa_client)->log_collector, &log_listener);
    if (error_code) 
    {
        printf("kaa_logging_set_listeners is failed to execute.....\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else
        printf("kaa_logging_set_listeners is executed successfully.....\n"); 

    /* kaa client will be started from here */  
    error_code = kaa_client_start(kaa_client, dummy_function, (void *)kaa_client, 0);  
    if (error_code) 
    {
        printf("kaa_client_start is failed to execute.....\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else
        printf("kaa_client_start is executed successfully.....\n");

    printf("after calling kaa_client_start.....\n");

    sleep(2);

    /* kaa client will be destroyed from here */
    kaa_client_destroy(kaa_client);

    printf("after calling kaa_client_destroy.....\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Let me know if need any more details from my-side.

Comment: Anyone has any update regarding this issue?

Comment: Hi,

I have tried to port CPP KAA SDK into Linux System and executed sample example with log upload which is working fine without any issue. So, it means KAA CPP SDK is working fine compare to KAA C SDK.

Comment: Do you have any logs?